# WebForm.ReportViewer Infinite Loop Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a strange problem in Visual Studio 2010 (C#) using the Report Viewer to load an RDL file.

I use the following code to load the RDL:

```
        //get the data set and then 
        //.
        //.
        //pass the report to the viewer            
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(_AccessReportDocument.FileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            this.AccessReportViewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(stream);
        }
        this.AccessReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

The issues is that once piece of code above reaches the last line, the code jumps to the page's Unload Method and then back to **this.AccessReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();** i.e. an infinite loop. Has anyone experienced this before? I have read that there are issues with the report viewer for vs 2010 but mainly with setting parameters, something I am not trying to do yet....

Debugging shows that all data sets etc are retrieved fine - so this is not the issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can occur with VS2010 if you are not checking for postbacks when setting the datasource. This is because of the changes made to the report viewer to load data asynchronously. Full explanation here:

[Reports Never Stop Loading With VS 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brianhartman/reports-never-stop-loading-with-vs-2010)

Comment: OK so I read the article and managed to solve the problem by adding a check to see if(!IsPostBack). If !IsPostBack==true, then I get the data and bind it to the report. This works, but I'm not sure I understand why it causes the report to load infinitely..

Comment: It's because if you're not checking for postbacks and are setting your datasource on page load then because the report viewer control itself makes an async postback to render itself, then this would cause your page to load and set the datasource again, resetting the report viewer and hence it all starts again.